# I want to pre-hardcode my fallbackfee settings

Tags: blockchain

I want to pre-hardcode my fallbackfee settings so that they are uniform across all wallet nodes. In which file should I put it, and not in bitcoin.conf?

Comment: Why would you not set it in bitcoin.conf?

Comment: @PieterWuille Because OP probably wants bitcoin.conf to be created from a common network location for several mirrored nodes. As seen in OP posts history, they are bootstrapping an alternative chain network.

Comment: When I try to send money from my windows wallet, I can't send money due to fallbackfee settings. I don't want non-coder users to have to set that up.